# Keep the CountDownTimer running after orientation change

Tags: java, countdowntimer, onsaveinstancestate, onrestoreinstancestate

I have made a CountDownTimer that works perfectly - you can get the correct time for soft/medium/hard-boiling an egg. My problem is that the timer resets after orientation change. I have googled and tried so many solution, still I don't understand how to use the onSave and onRestore properly. Here's my code:

Any tips?

```
    package com.dohman.boilaneggbae;

import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String CURRENT_TIME = "currentTime";
    private static final String DURATION_TIME = "durationTime";
    private long currentTime;
    private int durationTime;
    private TextView time;
    private Button buttonLargeSize;
    private Button buttonMediumSize;
    private Button buttonSoft;
    private Button buttonMedium;
    private Button buttonHard;
    private Button buttonHellaHard;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private EggSize mediumOrLarge = EggSize.UNDEFINED;
    private boolean alreadyRunning = false;

    enum EggSize {
        UNDEFINED, MEDIUM, LARGE;
    }

    private View.OnClickListener btnMediumSizeClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediumOrLarge = EggSize.MEDIUM;
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener btnLargeSizeClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediumOrLarge = EggSize.LARGE;
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener btnSoftClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if ((mediumOrLarge != EggSize.UNDEFINED) && (alreadyRunning == false)) {
                alreadyRunning = true;
                durationTime = 240;
                start(240);
            } else if (mediumOrLarge == EggSize.UNDEFINED) {
                time.setText("Choose size first");
            } else {
                alreadyRunning = false;
                cancel();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putLong(CURRENT_TIME, currentTime);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(DURATION_TIME, durationTime);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            currentTime = savedInstanceState.getLong(CURRENT_TIME);
            durationTime = savedInstanceState.getInt(DURATION_TIME);
        }

        time = findViewById(R.id.time);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        currentTime = savedInstanceState.getLong(CURRENT_TIME);
        durationTime = savedInstanceState.getInt(DURATION_TIME);

        currentTime -= durationTime;
    }

    private void start(int duration) {
        time.setText("");

        if (mediumOrLarge == EggSize.MEDIUM) {
            duration -= 60;
        }
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(duration * 1000, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                String text = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) % 60,
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) % 60);
                time.setText(text);
            }

        countDownTimer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can learn more about that from the [DOCUMENTATION](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#saras) and to achieve what you want. You could store the time the timer was started and its duration. Then, when you restore the state, you can recreate the timer for the `setDuration - (currentTime - timerStartedTime)` duration.

Comment: In what variable should I store the timer? String?

Comment: You can store the current time as a `long` and the duration as an `int`.

Comment: Now I have coded the best I can, and edited my submit and even removed unrelated codes for you easier to read. I have created onSave and onRestore and tried to find one way to save and restore, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this! Using this link:
https://codinginflow.com/code-examples/android/countdown-timer/part-2

Those are the codes:

```
package com.codinginflow.countdowntimerexample;

import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final long START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 600000;

    private TextView mTextViewCountDown;
    private Button mButtonStartPause;
    private Button mButtonReset;

    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;

    private boolean mTimerRunning;

    private long mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
    private long mEndTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextViewCountDown = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);

        mButtonStartPause = findViewById(R.id.button_start_pause);
        mButtonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);

        mButtonStartPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mTimerRunning) {
                    pauseTimer();
                } else {
                    startTimer();
                }
            }
        });

        mButtonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resetTimer();
            }
        });

        updateCountDownText();
    }

    private void startTimer() {
        mEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + mTimeLeftInMillis;

        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mTimerRunning = false;
                updateButtons();
            }
        }.start();

        mTimerRunning = true;
        updateButtons();
    }

    private void pauseTimer() {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        mTimerRunning = false;
        updateButtons();
    }

    private void resetTimer() {
        mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
        updateCountDownText();
        updateButtons();
    }

    private void updateCountDownText() {
        int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
        int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;

        String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);

        mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    }

    private void updateButtons() {
        if (mTimerRunning) {
            mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mButtonStartPause.setText("Pause");
        } else {
            mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");

            if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 1000) {
                mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if (mTimeLeftInMillis < START_TIME_IN_MILLIS) {
                mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putLong("millisLeft", mTimeLeftInMillis);
        outState.putBoolean("timerRunning", mTimerRunning);
        outState.putLong("endTime", mEndTime);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        mTimeLeftInMillis = savedInstanceState.getLong("millisLeft");
        mTimerRunning = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("timerRunning");
        updateCountDownText();
        updateButtons();

        if (mTimerRunning) {
            mEndTime = savedInstanceState.getLong("endTime");
            mTimeLeftInMillis = mEndTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
            startTimer();
        }
    }
}
```

*EDIT: For some reason I can't mark my own answer as a solution, but this problem is solved anyway. (Answered)*

Comment: You have to wait 48 hours to accept your own answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer As suggested please add essential parts to your answer. Links can become invalid in the future.